# RegEx Finding multiple matches with a quantifier

Tags: regex, powershell

I have this PowerShell code:

```
$uri = "http://charts.spotify.com/api/tracks/most_streamed/au/daily/latest"
$ContentType = "application/json"
$postblog = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri).Content -match 'track_name\S:\S(.*?)",'
$matches[1]
```

When I run this, I get this result:

```
FourFiveSeconds
```

Problem is, I know there are more songs than just this one song. And I know that the match I am using, the string of text "**track_name**" exists more than once. How can I change my RegEx so that it matches every match it can find? In other words, the expected output would be multiple matches, allowing me to list all the songs, e.g. `$matches[1]`, `$matches[2]`, `$matches[3]`, `$matches[4]`, etc.

Comment: Btw it looks like you are not using the var $ContentType

Comment: As for the regex, `-match` returns as soon as it finds the first match in the subject. For global matches, `[regex]::matches($text, $pattern)` ... However, DON'T USE regex to parse structured data like JSON. Regex is an overkill here and it's bound to fail.

Comment: The Select-String -AllMatches pipeline thing actually does not work because it selects one result from each line (which is a spectacularly weird behaviour)

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using `Invoke-WebRequest`, I assume you are using Powershell v4.0. Therefore, you can use `ConvertFrom-Json` on the data received and iterate over it, instead of using a regex solution:

```
$uri = "http://charts.spotify.com/api/tracks/most_streamed/au/daily/latest"
$ContentType = "application/json"
$postblog = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri).Content | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Now, the entire `tracks` data is available inside `$postblog.tracks` array.

Iterate over them to get the `track_url`s:

```
Foreach( $track in $postblog.tracks ) {
    Write-Output $track.track_url
}
```

---

### EDIT

Apparently, you can simply use:

```
Write-Output $postblog.tracks.track_url
```

instead of the `Foreach` code-block. Thanks to [@PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) for that :)

Comment: That seems like a way better solution than parsing the data with regex, well done.

Comment: Typo : it's `ConvertFrom-Json` here on W8.1/PS5

Comment: @sodawillow Ah, fixed. Thanks

Comment: As you already assume v3+, you can replace `foreach` loop with `$postblog.tracks.track_url`

Comment: @PetSerAl Whoa! =) Nice

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all, yes you are right, converting it to JSON gives me heaps more options and it is cleaner than using RegEx.

I have this script now, which should definitely do the trick.

```
$spotifytopsongs = @()
$uri = "http://charts.spotify.com/api/tracks/most_streamed/au/daily/latest"
$ContentType = "application/json"
$spotifyjson = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri).Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$spotifyjson.tracks | select -First 50 | % {$spotifytopsongs += @($_.artist_name + " - " + $_.track_name)}
cls;$spotifytopsongs
```